# Path helpers for nested controllers / namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes, nested-routes

I have routes structure:

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :currencies
  end
```

rake routes output:

```
admin_currencies     GET /admin/currencies(.:format) admin/currencies#index
                     POST /admin/currencies(.:format) admin/currencies#create
new_admin_currency   GET /admin/currencies/new(.:format) admin/currencies#new
edit_admin_currency  GET /admin/currencies/:id/edit(.:format) admin/currencies#edit
      admin_currency GET /admin/currencies/:id(.:format) admin/currencies#show
                     PUT /admin/currencies/:id(.:format) admin/currencies#update
                     DELETE /admin/currencies/:id(.:format) admin/currencies#destroy
```

Admin is a namespace.

The form generated by scaffold looks like

```
= form_for @currency do |f|
  - if @currency.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2
        = pluralize(@currency.errors.count, "error")
        prohibited this currency from being saved:
      %ul
        - @currency.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg
  .field
    = f.label :title
    %br/
    = f.text_field :title
  .field
    = f.label :iso_code
    %br/
    = f.text_field :iso_code
  .actions
    = f.submit
```

I've changed `= form_for @currency` to `= form_for admin_currencies_path(@currency)` but it still failing due to form`s action is /admin/currencies/new instead of /admin/currencies.

What I do wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `form_for [:admin, @currency]`.

Comment: It's usually considered proper to tick the green arrow for solutions people gave that answer your question.  Glad it's working.  :D